# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, curl, localhost, connection-refused, port-443

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64
Plesk version: Plesk Obsidian 18.0.47.5

Hi,

I am running XenForo Forum on my Plesk which running behind Cloudflare.
I get following erro log, which is showing me that the curl connection to localhost on port 443 is refused.
https://prnt.sc/hN7k9PsJUCA-

All curl’s to localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 are refused:

```
root@srv:~# curl -vv localhost:443
*   Trying ::1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to ::1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused

root@srv:~# curl -vv 127.0.0.1:443
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443: Connection refused

root@srv:~# curl -vv 0.0.0.0:443
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 443: Connection refused
```

UFW Firewall is disabled:

```
root@srv:~# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

netstat show me that port 443 is active and listen:
https://prnt.sc/CqBFLdPYneBB

To be sure I also have turn OFF the “Security Level” on CF Firewall.
https://prnt.sc/S_z-4jgTaNCU

No matter what I’ve tried, so far unfortunately without success.

I would therefore be very grateful for any tip or solution to solve this issue.

Regards.

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic

Comment: Your first screenshot shows that something is listening on that port, but not on the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`). You are trying to access it via the loopback interface. Use the correct interface.